# Is it possible to use Windows FSRM or alternatives on multiple servers with multiple partitions?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, file-sharing

At my company we have multiple servers with multiple partitions that are shared for different users. Some users have rights to multiple partitions on different servers.

In order to limit the space they waste, we use [FSRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731206(v=ws.10).aspx) (File Server Resource Manager) to generate reports of large files, duplicate Files, etc.

We can compare files on different partitions within the same server, but we can not check multiple servers at the same time. This would be useful to deal with duplicate files.

Is there a way to configure FSRM reports to be able to compare partitions on multiple servers at the same time? Or maybe are there some different solutions for this?

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you running? 
Are you using DFS between any of the server shares?

Comment: @SturdyErde - sorry for the late reply, Windows 2008 R2. Yes we use DFS

Answer (score 1):

For reporting you can use something like Netwrix Auditor. Among other features it has file analysis reports including 'largest files' and 'duplicate files' across multiple file servers.
https://www.netwrix.com/file_analysis_reports.html